# Any alternative for nesting observer in room database?

Tags: android-room, android-livedata

I'm quite new to programming!
I have solved the problem by following way.
Any alternative to NESTING is appreciated.
Thanks.
Using Kotlin with room database.

I get fine result by following way. But nesting for more than 3 times is not handy solution. I know I have to learn more..

1. observing and getting the dateString value
2. then passing it through second observer..

```
userViewModel.getUser(userId!!).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {user->
    val dateStr = JSONObject(user.setting).getString("date")
    payViewModel.getAllPayDate(sdf.parse(dateStr)).observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
        Observer {pay->
           //geting the ui related values here..
    })
})
```